# How do I center my logo image to another div in CSS horizontally and vertically?

Tags: html, css, navigation, graphical-logo

I need help positioning a logo horizontally center. It also needs to be centered vertically to the top of my links `div`. Can someone help me?

I'd like my logo to look like this:
[image]

Below is my HTML and CSS:

**HTML -** http://codebin.org/view/199faa14

```
<div id="container">

      <div id="logo">
      <img src="images/images/logo.gif" />
      </div>

      <div id="navigation">
      navigation
      </div>

      <div id="header">
      </div>

      <div id="line">
      </div>

      <div id="content">
      content
      </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS -** http://codebin.org/view/dda88d94

```
body {
background: url(../images/images/bg_page.gif) center center;
}

#container {
width: 940px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

    #header {
    height: 281px;
    background: url(../images/home/header.gif) top center;
    position: relative;
    }

    #logo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0px
    height: 214px;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
    }

    #navigation {
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    margin-top: 100px
    }

    #content {
    height: 541px;
    background: url(../images/home/bg_body.png) top center;
    position: relative;
    }

    #line {
    height: 4px;
    background: url(../images/home/line.gif) top center;
    position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: You should update your question, no need add links in comments.

Comment: Please include the code + format the question properly next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this before using javascript!

```
.center {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%; 
margin-left: -150px;
margin-top: -150px;
}
```

or this!

```
.image_container {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   background: #eee;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 300px;
 }

.image_container img {
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Comment: worked like a charm the first one thanks for the help much appreciated! i just put the logo into the navigation div and used it as container for it

Comment: no prob! :) when you can set this post as the right answer if it solved your problems

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question. Since you are calling out your logo img in the html, try this.

```
<div id="logo">
 <img src="images/images/logo.gif" alt="logo" align="center"/>
</div>
```

Comment: The align attribute is not supported in HTML 5 and is deprecated in HTML 4.01

Comment: and in the CSS, you would need to change your code for the 

#logo img{

//enter code here

}

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with:

- display:inline-block;
- line-height;
- negative margin
- text-align:justify (you have 5 items 4 links & 1 img in middle)
- :after

Demo made in a similar context for someone else :
http://dabblet.com/gist/5375725

Answer (score 0):

Some people will facing some problems while using the vertical-align: middle; styling attribute. CSS needs to be written in the prober way. For people looking for a quick fix.

```
.logo { left:0; top:0; height:100%; width:100px; }

<div class="logo" style="background:url('/assets/images/site-logo.png') center center no-repeat;">
  <img src="/site/logo.png" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

*make sure the container has the position:relative; css attribute.

It's easy handeling retina and compatible with all kind of CSS markups. hope this simple technique can save some time for people :)